# ERROR: type "exception" does not exist in the PostgreSQL block

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addl_field_pkg.del_symm_dopl224_sp ( i_ORDE_NO varchar(30), 
i_ACTN_CODE varchar(30), i_CIRC_NO varchar(30), i_ADDL_FIELD text,
 i_ADDL_FIELD_ACTN text, i_ADDL_CONTENT text, o_ERR_CODE INOUT bigint, o_ERR_MSG INOUT text ) AS $body$
DECLARE

      ORDER_COMPLETED_EX    exception;   
      w_order_no                  varchar(20);
    
BEGIN
        if ( current_setting('addl_field_pkg.w_completed')::char = milestone_pkg.CHK_IPLC_ORDER_STATUS_F(i_orde_no) ) then
               raise ORDER_COMPLETED_EX;
        end if;
        select orde_no into STRICT w_order_no
               from symm_dopl224
               where orde_no = i_orde_no
               and    actn_code = i_actn_code
               and    circ_no   = i_circ_no
               and    addl_field  = i_addl_field
               and    addl_field_actn = i_addl_field_actn
               and    addl_content    = i_addl_content;
        delete from symm_dopl224
               where orde_no = i_orde_no
               and    actn_code = i_actn_code
               and    circ_no   = i_circ_no
               and    addl_field  = i_addl_field
               and    addl_field_actn = i_addl_field_actn
               and    addl_content    = i_addl_content;
    Exception
             when no_data_found then
                  ROLLBACK;
                  o_err_code := SQLSTATE;
                  o_err_msg := 'Update failure - Record does not exist';
             when others then
                  ROLLBACK;
                  o_err_code := SQLSTATE;
                  o_err_msg := 'System error - '||sqlerrm;
    END;

$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
```

Comment: kindly help me not able to encounter the issue.

Comment: No it does not. Remove the declaration of ORDER_COMPLETED_EX and use `raise exception 'ORDER_COMPLETED_EX'` in the body.